# Repeater Control With SeparatorTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, separator

How to create horizontal line after each row in repeater control ? I think that I should use "SeparatorTemplate", I tried but didn't work. Can you tell me where to put the separator in the code, to make each line separated ?

This is my code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="EmployeesRepeater" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                       First Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Last Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Title
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        HomePhone
                    </th>
                </tr>           
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("FirstName") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("LastName") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("Title") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("HomePhone") %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>    
        </FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Isn't the end line of the ItemTemplate the spot for the separation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just put in a new row with an `<hr>` in it in your `ItemTemplate`.

Eg:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%#Eval("FirstName") %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%#Eval("LastName") %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%#Eval("Title") %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%#Eval("HomePhone") %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><hr></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

or use the `SeparatorTemplate`:

```
<SeparatorTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><hr></td>
    </tr>
</SeparatorTemplate>
```

Here is some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.separatortemplate.aspx) on how a the `SeperatorTemplate` works.

**EDIT:**  The `SeparatorTemplate` is great for when you need to do summary formatting or something that requires more HTML, controls, binding, etc.  If you are looking for just adding lines you should be just using css to style the rows appropriately to get the desired output.

Comment: This work. What do you think about vertical line ? How can I do it ?

Comment: @TheChampp not sure what you mean about a vertical line.  You could add a border to your `tr` or `td` to get a vertical line effect.

Comment: I typed border:"1px solid red" and on the "<table>" tag worked but on "<th>" and "<td>" tags didn't work. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

If you set the appropriate style to the `tr` element should be enough. There's no need to create an extra row just for adding a separator.

For example:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="item">
   ....

style
{
    .item {
        border-bottom:1px solid #cfcfcf;
     }
}
```